# bash find -print cuts out results?

Tags: bash, find

**EDIT:** I have narrowed the scope of my question and changed the title to reflect that.

I'm having trouble understanding why `find`'s `-print` cuts out some results.

In the no-print example, it displays as expected. When we add the `-print` option it cuts out a number of the results. In this case, it seems like the results it cuts are anything in a `build` folder and also `src`?

**Without `print`**

```sh
$ find . -type f -name "*.rs" -or -name "*.dylib"  

./target/release/deps/libpaste_impl-f7b2dfa71f5079c3.dylib
./target/release/deps/libderivative-82fe3bf231ffd983.dylib
./target/release/deps/libproc_macro_hack-a11693f905f89c54.dylib
./target/release/deps/libnum_derive-8dd64bf06977ab17.dylib
./target/release/deps/liblewton-7f74c0936a55669b.dylib
./target/release/build/gfx_gl-9371e5933c9b30cd/out/gl_bindings.rs
./target/release/build/glutin-949d080876b75405/out/test_gl_bindings.rs
./target/release/build/glutin-949d080876b75405/out/gl_bindings.rs
./target/release/build/clang-sys-5a62f89d3a7aac29/out/dynamic.rs
./target/release/build/clang-sys-5a62f89d3a7aac29/out/common.rs
./target/release/build/bindgen-90310930123f8d37/out/tests.rs
./target/release/build/khronos_api-6a83e1455caf2a52/out/webgl_exts.rs
./target/release/build/cgmath-2f7f8d69317ede14/out/swizzle_operator_macro.rs
./target/release/build/coreaudio-sys-102943d1a92d8237/out/coreaudio.rs
./target/release/build/gleam-53db59dff8c0c2d5/out/gl_and_gles_bindings.rs
./target/release/build/gleam-53db59dff8c0c2d5/out/gles_bindings.rs
./target/release/build/gleam-53db59dff8c0c2d5/out/gl_bindings.rs
./target/release/build/typenum-fa3bdd92a2254aff/out/consts.rs
./target/release/build/typenum-fa3bdd92a2254aff/out/tests.rs
./target/release/build/typenum-fa3bdd92a2254aff/out/op.rs
./target/release/build/khronos_api-097c24980964af45/out/webgl_exts.rs
./target/release/build/three-e70ffd55e3adc8b9/out/data.rs
./target/debug/deps/libderivative-2f106744ef2c3322.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libderivative-2f106744ef2c3322.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libnum_derive-69c598476fa9ab31.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libnum_derive-69c598476fa9ab31.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libpaste_impl-a70f0a4520e10125.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libpaste_impl-a70f0a4520e10125.dylib
./target/debug/deps/liblewton-502bad4119a8f69a.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/liblewton-502bad4119a8f69a.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libproc_macro_hack-55f7753a4ce25bd1.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libproc_macro_hack-55f7753a4ce25bd1.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libproc_macro_hack-55f7753a4ce25bd1.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libpaste_impl-a70f0a4520e10125.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libderivative-2f106744ef2c3322.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libnum_derive-69c598476fa9ab31.dylib
./target/debug/deps/liblewton-502bad4119a8f69a.dylib
./target/debug/build/clang-sys-8c62fd28e328b848/out/dynamic.rs
./target/debug/build/clang-sys-8c62fd28e328b848/out/common.rs
./target/debug/build/khronos_api-d97fe936539cf92d/out/webgl_exts.rs
./target/debug/build/khronos_api-f0e964efb9ead6fb/out/webgl_exts.rs
./target/debug/build/bindgen-e9d8da9bd8e8a49e/out/tests.rs
./target/debug/build/three-f0ac8127d3dafbd5/out/data.rs
./target/debug/build/typenum-0cccc5396cc94b61/out/consts.rs
./target/debug/build/typenum-0cccc5396cc94b61/out/tests.rs
./target/debug/build/typenum-0cccc5396cc94b61/out/op.rs
./target/debug/build/coreaudio-sys-6fcf2f1dc6932dd6/out/coreaudio.rs
./target/debug/build/cgmath-b8a84179fd24b352/out/swizzle_operator_macro.rs
./target/debug/build/gleam-bd168af6fddd9da9/out/gl_and_gles_bindings.rs
./target/debug/build/gleam-bd168af6fddd9da9/out/gles_bindings.rs
./target/debug/build/gleam-bd168af6fddd9da9/out/gl_bindings.rs
./target/debug/build/gfx_gl-a69ffadf539b9028/out/gl_bindings.rs
./target/debug/build/glutin-a350d8c7a6ce351c/out/test_gl_bindings.rs
./target/debug/build/glutin-a350d8c7a6ce351c/out/gl_bindings.rs
./benches/my_benchmark.rs
./src/lib.rs
./src/boid.rs
./src/main.rs
```

**With `print`**

```sh
$ find . -type f -name "*.rs" -or -name "*.dylib" -print

./target/release/deps/libpaste_impl-f7b2dfa71f5079c3.dylib
./target/release/deps/libderivative-82fe3bf231ffd983.dylib
./target/release/deps/libproc_macro_hack-a11693f905f89c54.dylib
./target/release/deps/libnum_derive-8dd64bf06977ab17.dylib
./target/release/deps/liblewton-7f74c0936a55669b.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libderivative-2f106744ef2c3322.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libderivative-2f106744ef2c3322.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libnum_derive-69c598476fa9ab31.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libnum_derive-69c598476fa9ab31.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libpaste_impl-a70f0a4520e10125.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libpaste_impl-a70f0a4520e10125.dylib
./target/debug/deps/liblewton-502bad4119a8f69a.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/liblewton-502bad4119a8f69a.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libproc_macro_hack-55f7753a4ce25bd1.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libproc_macro_hack-55f7753a4ce25bd1.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libproc_macro_hack-55f7753a4ce25bd1.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libpaste_impl-a70f0a4520e10125.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libderivative-2f106744ef2c3322.dylib
./target/debug/deps/libnum_derive-69c598476fa9ab31.dylib
./target/debug/deps/liblewton-502bad4119a8f69a.dylib
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue!

Turns out it was a scoping problem.

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.rs" -or -name "*.dylib"
```

evaluates as

```sh
find . \( -type f -name "*.rs" -or -name "*.dylib" \) -print
```

Whereas

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.rs" -or -name "*.dylib" -print
```

evaluates as

```sh
find . \( -type f -name "*.rs" \) -or  \( -name "*.dylib" -print \)
```

So the `-type f -name "*.rs"` had no associated action with it, and never gets printed.

Please let me know if I understood this incorrectly.

Comment: I think you're right. From [this](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) link: Please note that `-a` when specified implicitly (for example by two
       tests appearing without an explicit operator between them) or
       explicitly has higher precedence than `-o`.  This means that `find .
       -name afile -o -name bfile -print` will never print `afile`.